# Open a given URL (in Chrome) on button click event in Javascript- duplicate

Tags: javascript, buttonclick

In our current project, We have created a Dashboard where we have several buttons. When we click on button in the back-end it performs some action (button click event) defined using JavaScript. Now, I want to **open a given URL on button click event in Chrome**. The code for HTML page (dashboard) is shown below:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to Internet of Things, Service and People Portal</title>
<HTA:APPLICATION
  APPLICATIONNAME="Run Exe or Bat files from HTA by Hackoo"
  ID="MyHTMLapplication"
  VERSION="1.0"/>
</head>
<style type="text/css"> 
#below { height:210px; width:500px; border: 2px solid black}
</style>

<script>
function Dashboard() {
    var redirectWindow = window.open('http://localhost:8686/temperature', 'blank');
    redirectWindow.location;
};
</script>

<body>

</div>
<div id="below">
<h1>Control </h1>   
<input style="width: 110px; height:100px;color: white; background-color: #203040; 
font-family:Book Antiqua;" img src="images/Dashboard.png" type="image"  onClick="Dashboard();"/>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Here when I click on Dashboard button it open given URL in Internet explorer. I want to open in Chrome. Is there any specific thing to open given URL in chrome??? Am I missing something??

Comment: You can not open a window in another browser.

Comment: @epascarello- Why is there any specific reason ??? Can I add security to open in Chrome ??

Comment: Because there is nothing built into browsers/javascript to do it.  You can look to see if there are activeX controls that will do it, but with modern day IE basically locking down activeX, I  doubt  it will work nicely anymore.

Answer (score 0):

If you had opened the original page in chrome, clicking the link will surely open as a new window in chrome. We cannot open windows in chrome if the original application was opened in IE vice versa.

Comment: I had already opened page in chrome. But it will open a new given URL in IE. Am I missing something ??? Should I need to download chrome with Admin permission ?? I have without admin permission.

Comment: Created a fiddle for this

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/xtz9mgmw/

This works as expected. If i open this in chrome the new windows opens in chrome regardless of my default browser settings.

Comment: Again it will open in IE.